# snapshot.ConnectionState is always waiting FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am doing a function call onload of the widget but I am getting ConnectionState as waiting always. I tried printing the snapshot values and got this

```
"AsyncSnapshot<Response<TimesheetData>>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null, null)"
```

**Heres the screen**

```
  class _TimesheetState extends State<Timesheet> {
  CalendarController _calendarController;
  @override
  initState() {
    _calendarController = CalendarController();
    final DateTime today = DateTime.now();
    _calendarController.selectedDate = DateTime(
      today.year,
      today.month,
      today.day,
    );
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      TimesheetBloc bloc = TimesheetProvider.of(context);
      bloc.fetchTimesheetData();
    });
  }

  List<Meeting> meetings;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    TimesheetBloc bloc = TimesheetProvider.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
        body: Theme(
      data: ThemeData(primarySwatch: materialColorPrimary),
      child: StreamBuilder<Response<TimesheetData>>(
          stream: bloc.monthlyEventsStream,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
            print('snapchot:${snapshot}');
            if(snapshot.hasError){
              return Text('error: ${snapshot.hasError}');
            } else{
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                switch (snapshot.data.status) {
                  case Status.LOADING:
                    return Loading(loadingMessage: snapshot.data.message);
                    break;
                  case Status.COMPLETED:
                    return SfCalendar(
                      dataSource: MeetingDataSource(_getDataSource()),
                      view: CalendarView.month,
                      showNavigationArrow: true,
                      monthViewSettings: MonthViewSettings(
                        showAgenda: true,
                        agendaStyle: AgendaStyle(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                          appointmentTextStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontSize: 13, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                          dateTextStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: primaryColor, fontSize: 13, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                        ),
                      ),
                      controller: _calendarController,
                      onTap: _openForm,
                    );
                    break;
                  case Status.ERROR:
                    return Error(
                      errorMessage: snapshot.data.message,
                      onRetryPressed: () => bloc.fetchTimesheetData(),
                    );
                    break;
                }
              }
              return Container();
            }

  }
  ),
    ));
  }

  List<Meeting> _getDataSource() {
    meetings = <Meeting>[];
    final DateTime today = DateTime.now();
    final DateTime startTime =
        DateTime(today.year, today.month, today.day, 9, 0, 0);
    final DateTime endTime = startTime.add(const Duration(hours: 2));
    meetings
        .add(Meeting('Conference', startTime, endTime, primaryColor, false));
    return meetings;
  }

  _openForm(CalendarTapDetails details) {
    //code
    }

  _addTask() {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Task added')));
    }
  }
}
```

**Here's the bloc file**

```
class TimesheetBloc{
  TimesheetRepository _timesheetRepository = new TimesheetRepository();
  StreamController _monthly = StreamController<Response<TimesheetData>>();

  //declare streams
  final _monthlyEvents = BehaviorSubject<Response<TimesheetData>>();

  //get data from streams
  Stream<Response<TimesheetData>> get monthlyEventsStream => _monthlyEvents.stream;

  //set data
  StreamSink<Response<TimesheetData>> get monthlyEventsSink => _monthly.sink;

  //dispose
    _monthlyEvents?.close();
    _monthly?.close();

  }   

  fetchTimesheetData() async {
    var months = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov','dec'];
    monthlyEventsSink.add(Response.loading('Fetching Data.'));
    try {
      SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      Map json = jsonDecode(pref.getString('user'));
      var loginDetails = LoginModel.fromJson(json);
      DateTime today = DateTime.now();
      var currentMonth =today.month - 1;
      TimesheetData data =
      await _timesheetRepository.getTimesheetDataMonthly(months[currentMonth], loginDetails.id, loginDetails.token);
      monthlyEventsSink.add(Response.completed(data));
    } catch (e) {
      monthlyEventsSink.add(Response.error(e.toString()));
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Please check the screenshot

[image]

I tried returning the response in fetchTimesheetData but still getting the waiting status.
How can I fix this?

Comment: this is because no events are added to `_monthlyEvents`

Comment: Aah!! my bad. Thank you @pskink for pointing it out.